# How to export to Excel with a SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, excel

I want to create a SharePoint List where a user uses the People picker to select someone but the information on the list should be

```
Name, Title, Department and Phone.
```

I can't figure out how to accomplish this.

I have Excel 2016 and InfoPath 2013 installed if I need to use it

Comment: You can't figure out how to accomplish what? Exporting to excel or creating a list? People picker comes with a field of type 'Person or Group'

Comment: Getting attributes from People picker into a List that can be exported to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able, in Excel, to edit a SharePoint list, including columns of type "Person or Group", this is not possible out of the box. Communication between Excel and SharePoint lists OOTB is limited to import an Excel spreasheet as a new SharePoint list, or export a SharePoint list to a new Excel file. No "roundtrip" / bidirectional sync.

It is only possible to do two-way data synchronization between Excel and a SharePoint list with third party products, such as the one my company has developed: [SharePoint list Synchronizer](https://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com).